# Is it possible make predicate from List?

Tags: list, prolog, predicate

I use SWI-Prolog

I have lists like this

```
[sunny,hot,high,weak,no]
```

and

```
[outlook,temperature,humidity,wind,play_tennis]
```

I want to make a predicate like

```
run(no,  [outlook=sunny,    temp=hot,  humidity=high,   wind=weak  ]).
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is, but not if you don't have a spec of how the predicate should behave.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, but you're going to have to implement the appropriate machine learning algorithm (your example looks identical to the ones found in Mitchell's machine learning book, is this a homework assignment?).

Note that you can use the `=..` operator to turn a list into a predicate, which might help you if I've misunderstood your original question. In other words, `A=..[a,b,c]` binds `a(b,c)` to `A`